# WeakReference for Android activity which is created using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am maintaining activity `list` in my application. Whenever any activity created, a `weak reference` of that activity will get pushed to the `list`.

Lets say, I have created four activity in given order : ActivityA => ActivityB => ActivityC => ActivityD.
Here, ActivityD is started with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.
`list` will have all weak references of all of these activity.

Now, When I press `Home` button, App will go in background. After some time when we start the App again and print the `list` then all the references for ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC are `null`, But reference to ActivityD is still present. I am not storing/holding any STRONG reference to any activity.

If I start `ActivityD` without `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag then value of reference to `ActivityD` in `list` is `null`.

So, My questions are,

Why this is happening?

Is android storing any reference to activity which is getting started using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`?

Answer (score 0):

When your app goes to background all your activities save their state. Android remembers that it should launch activity D with the same `Intent` when the app goes to foreground.

If you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` android uses the same instance of activity, thus, your weak reference will be still valid because activity D will be the same object.

Without this flag android will create a new instance of activity and your weak reference will return null because old activity D object is garbage collected.